# Find last job change date with JOB_TITLE and EVENT_DATE

Tags: sql, azure, databricks

Hi I am working in an Azure Databricks and I am looking for a SQL query solution.

Assuming that my db has five columns:

| ID | EVENT_DATE | JOB_TITLE | PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-01-01 | VP1 | 100,000 |
| 12345 | 2020-01-10 | VP1 | 90,000 |
| 12345 | 2019-01-20 | Analyst1 | 80,000 |
| 12346 | 2021-02-01 | VP2 | 200,000 |
| 12346 | 2020-02-10 | Analyst2 | 150,000 |
| 12346 | 2020-01-20 | Analyst2 | 110,000 |

Basically I want the EVENT_DATE when JOB_TITLE changed the last time. This is my desired output:

| ID | JOB_TITLE | PAY | LAST_JOB_CHANGE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | VP1 | 90,000 | 2021-01-10 |
| 12346 | VP2 | 200,000 | 2021-02-01 |

For the last column LAST_JOB_CHANGE_DATE, we are pulling from the 2nd and 4th row of the table because that's the date when they changed job the last time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a simpler solution for this but the following should work.

I'm assuming you wanted the MOST resent job change for each employee. To illustrate this, I added an extra row for an Engineer1. The `ROW_NUMBER()` window function helps us with this.

| ID | EVENT_DATE | JOB_TITLE | PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 2021-01-01 | VP1 | 100,000 |
| 12345 | 2020-01-10 | VP1 | 90,000 |
| 12345 | 2019-01-20 | Analyst1 | 80,000 |
| 12345 | 2018-01-04 | Engineer1 | 75,000 |
| 12346 | 2021-02-01 | VP2 | 200,000 |
| 12346 | 2020-02-10 | Analyst2 | 150,000 |
| 12346 | 2020-01-20 | Analyst2 | 110,000 |

Here is the query:

```
SELECT <---- (4)
c.ID,
c.JOB_TITLE,
c.PAY,
c.last_job_change_date
FROM
(
  SELECT <---- (3)
  b.ID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY b.last_job_change_date DESC) AS row_id,
  b.JOB_TITLE,
  b.PAY,
  b.last_job_change_date
  FROM
  (
    SELECT <---- (2)
    a.ID,
    a.JOB_TITLE,
    a.PAY,
    a.EVENT_DATE as last_job_change_date
    FROM
    (
      SELECT <---- (1)
      ID,
      EVENT_DATE,
      PAY,
      JOB_TITLE,
      LEAD(JOB_TITLE, 1) OVER (
          PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC) job_change
      FROM yourtable
    ) a
    WHERE JOB_TITLE <> job_change
  ) b
) c
WHERE row_id = 1
```

I used a 4 step process and annotated the query with each step:

1. Returns a table with a column for the subsequent job title (ordered by most recent title) of each employee.
2. Returns the table from (1) but removes rows where the employee did not change their job
3. Add row numbers so we can get the most recent job change of each employee
4. Return most recent job changes for each employee

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `INNER JOIN` to accomplish that, ie

```
%sql
SELECT a.*
FROM yourTable a 
  INNER JOIN 
  ( 
  SELECT id, MAX(event_date) event_date 
  FROM yourTable b
  GROUP BY id
  ) b ON a.id = b.id 
  AND a.event_date = b.event_date
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` approach would also work well:

```
%sql
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY event_date DESC  ) AS rn, 
  *
FROM yourTable a 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

My results:

[image: My results]